# SQL Group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE actions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, key1 NUMERIC, key2 NUMERIC);
```

I'm not even sure how to explain this so I think it's best i give an example:

```
id  key1 key2
1   1    1
2   1    2
3   1    1
4   2    1
5   2    3
```

to ouput something like this:

```
key1 key2 count(id)
1    1    2
1    2    1
2    1    1
2    3    1
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work, because i need the key1 field to not be unique :

```
Select  key1,key2,count(id)  from actions group by key2, order by key1
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you group by both: key1 and key2? This way key1 will not be unique. Unique will be the combination of keys.

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT key1, key2, COUNT(id) FROM actions GROUP BY key1, key2 ORDER BY key1, key2
```

Answer (score 5):

In the GROUP clause, you have to write **all** the fields that aren't in the agregate (COUNT, MAX, MIN). So, in this case, you need to add the key1 field, as this:

```
Select  key1, key2, count(id)  
from actions 
group by key1, key2 
order by key1
```